# How do I curl my elasticsearch on AWS EC2

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I installed elasticsearch(docker) 8.2 on  aws ec2(ubuntu 20.04.)

Everything is working.My only problem is that I can't reach(curl) it from other instances and my backend server(it is on same vpc).

I added my node to its discovery node, and also set network.host: 0.0.0.0
but I still can't reach it
(I tried with both private and public ip)
Is it necessary to install SSL/TSL on it with elastic 8?
Does anyone has any suggestion how to access it?

Comment: Paris, thanks for marking answer, please upvote the answer as well, by clicking the up arrow in front of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to bind the docker container port to host port, you need to add below config, to your Elasticsearch container docker yml

```
ports:
      - "9202:9200" (bind 9200 port of host to docker port of 9200, 9200 is the Elasticsearch port by default)
```

After that you should be able to do the curl from other instances in the VPC.